# read comma separated integers in INI file

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I have a INI file that looks like this !

```
[columnNumber]
Number1=2,4
```

this is my code
the ini file is [read using function defined here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_files_ini.php)

the columberNumber is taken as string "2,4" i want to split this and pass it into my select case object mytmp looping for all values in Number1 pass it to mytmp in select

```
columnNum = ReadIni(file, "columnNumber", "Number1")
    mytmp = columnNum
    x = Split(mytmp, ",")
    For k = 0 To UBound(x)
    'mytmp1 = Split(array_colnum, ",")
    'mytmp2 = Search(array_col)


    'mytmp1 = x(k)
    'mytmp2 = x(k)
    Next k
```

this is my select case

```
select case i...<does something>

       select case mytmp
```

Could somebody guide me in doing this!

Updated : I want to put in `select case i` the values got from [columnNumber] my ReadIni function reads from [columnNumber section] the number1={2,4} i want to split this and store in a variable, the variable is read from select case variable

Comment: Can you be more clear with your question? It's difficult to tell what you are actually asking

Comment: i updated the question if now you can check this ! pls

Answer (score 3):

It's not completly clear what exactly you trying to do...
what is "I" variable? what it should contain?

```
    mytmp = "2,4"
    x = Split(mytmp, ",")

    For k = LBound (x) To UBound (x)
            '## Get value and store in variable "I".
            i = x (k) 

            Select Case i
                    Case "2"
                            Response.Write "yep, it's 2"
                    Case "4"
                            Response.Write "yep, it's 4"
            End Select
    Next
```

Comment: ok! +1 but case shouldn't be separate say like `a[2]={2,4} select case i` how to do like this.

Comment: at Zam! `x = Split(columnNum, ",")
For k = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
i = x(k)

mytmp = Val(i)`  in this mytmp gives me 2,how to loop to get 4 ?

Comment: 2 -- that is right, because you have only 2 value. if you need to pass 4 times, than you should 

1) parse all and find highest value (is our case will be 4).
2) you should move SELECT CASE outside "For k = LBound (x) To UBound (x)"